# Python modules not working after installing them to local environment using conda on Windows

Tags: python, conda

let me prefice by saying that I am somewhat new to python.

So i cant seem to access a package after I import it. 
Here is an example:

```
 C:\Users\Tyler
(base) λ conda install beautifulsoup4
Solving environment: done

# All requested packages already installed.


    C:\Users\Tyler
    (base) λ python
    Python 3.6.4 (v3.6.4:d48eceb, Dec 19 2017, 06:04:45) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
    Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
    >>> import beautifulsoup4
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'beautifulsoup4'
```

I can't seem to figure this out. I have read some things about changing your .bashrc file but I can't seem to find one.

Also my PYTHONPATH is not set to anything, so that is not the issue.

below is my conda info

```
conda info



    active environment : base
    active env location : C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3
            shell level : 1
       user config file : C:\Users\Tyler\.condarc
 populated config files : C:\Users\Tyler\.condarc
          conda version : 4.5.0
    conda-build version : 3.0.27
         python version : 3.6.4.final.0
       base environment : C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3  (writable)
           channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/pro/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/pro/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
          package cache : C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\pkgs
                          C:\Users\Tyler\AppData\Local\conda\conda\pkgs
       envs directories : C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs
                          C:\Users\Tyler\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs
                          C:\Users\Tyler\.conda\envs
               platform : win-64
             user-agent : conda/4.5.0 requests/2.18.4 CPython/3.6.4 Windows/10 Windows/10.0.16299
          administrator : True
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

P.S: importing as `from bs4 import beautifulsoup` throws `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named bs4`

Comment: The package is imported as `bs4`, not `beautifulsoup4`... See, e.g., the documentation: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Comment: importing as "from bs4 import beautifulsoup" throws a module not found error as well.

Comment: FYI a .bashrc is for linux's default shell, bash.

Comment: Can you please show the output of `python -c "import sys; print(sys.executable)"`? I think the Python you're running is not the one from Anaconda. Do you have another Python installed?

Comment: @darthbith the output is C:\Users\Tyler\python.exe  and i am not sure, how could I found this out?

Comment: That's usually not where Anaconda installs it's Python. You should use the "Anaconda Prompt" from the Start Menu to run Anaconda's Python. If you want to use Bash on Windows (e.g., from WSL) you need to provide a lot more detail of how you installed Anaconda, etc.

Comment: @darthbith tried using the anaconda prompt python and I still get the same errors. At this point should I just uninstall all versions of python and anaconda and just start fresh?

Comment: Yes, that's probably a good idea

Answer (score 0):

I had multiple versions of python installed on my machine. Thanks for everyone's help!